# jConsole keeps disconnecting when using micrometer-registry-jmx and GuavaCacheMetrics, Spring 2.3 upgrade

Tags: spring, guava, jmx, jconsole, micrometer

This happened after upgrading from Spring 2.1 to 2.3. When using both GuavaCacheMetrics.monitor(...) and io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-jmx, jConsole keeps disconnecting. If I remove either of these, the other seems to work fine. Server will print this message sometimes: "The server has decided to close this client connection."

Answer (score 0):

I had:
cassandraPersistentEntity.getTableName().asCql(false);
Instead of:
cassandraPersistentEntity.getTableName().asCql(true);

asCql(false) adds quotes to the string and was causing jConsole to throw a parse error.